# Easier way to highlight text in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

When I read PDF, I constantly highlight text. But the **distance** between the `text` and the `Highlight` button is quite far,  like this:
[image]

and this becomes very **annoying** when I need to do a lot of highlight.

I'm wondering if there is any plugin could provide alternative shortcuts for `highlight`?, for example, `double-click` text to highlight, or a `nearby prompt button` after selecting a text.

How can I do it?

Notice: Someone may argue that I can click `Highlight` button first, and then every text I select would be highlighted, but this would negate the action of `select`. For me, I `constantly` selecting text when reading PDF, it's just a habit of reading things, and I don't want to highlight them.

Comment: You can use a different PDF authoring tool or enable the `Comment` menu that opens to the side.

Answer (score 1):

Use a shortcut, you have to enable them first in your preferences, here is the adobe list of shortcuts and how to access them [click me](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/keyboard-shortcuts.html)

Comment: Yes, there is only a shortcut for `selecting highlight tool`. It's not changeable, and I can't use it to highlight after selecting a text. It's only for `selecting highlight tool`. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an autohotkey script with a code like this one. It basically "clicks" for you where you want.

```
!^+h::             ; Alt(!) CTRL(^) shift(+) AND "h"    
MouseMove, 383, 77  ; relative position of the Acrobat "Highlight button" 
Sleep, 100
MouseClick
return
```

**How to use it:**

1. First you need to install Autohotkey
2. Then create a file myshorcut.ahk with the code above and move this file in your start menu (on windows C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
3. In Acrobat, select the  text you want to highlight and press your chosen shortcut (in my code it’s Alt + CTRL + shift + h)

   - You can use the AHK Window Spy (provided with autohotkey) to find the position needed for your code (windows or button name etc.)

You can also add just before the return a new line with `Send, {CTRLDOWN}s{CTRLUP}{ESC}`. This will save the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Here  is a more exact way to highlight any text in Adobe PDF document:
^+h::      ; CTRL(^) shift(+) AND "h"
ControlClick, AVL_AVView2, 222.pdf - Adobe Acrobat Pro,, Left, 1,  NA
Sleep, 100
return

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you [edit] your answer to explain what you are suggesting?